# GridView to DataTable: Skip certain Columns

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datatable

Please read this code:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    For Each col As DataControlField In GridView1.Columns
        dt.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText)
    Next

    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim nrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        Dim z As Integer = 0
        For Each col As DataControlField In GridView1.Columns
            nrow(z) = row.Cells(z).Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "")
            z += 1
        Next
        dt.Rows.Add(nrow)
    Next
```

How can I skip certain columns of the gridview? For example: Columns 1, 3 and 6

Thanks All for your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
For Each col As DataControlField In GridView1.Columns
If (col.Index <> 1) and (col.Index <> 3) and (col.Index <> 6) then
dt.Columns.Add(col.HeaderText)
End If
Next
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
Dim nrow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
Dim z As Integer = 0
For Each col As DataControlField In GridView1.Columns
If (col.Index <> 1) and (col.Index <> 3) and (col.Index <> 6) then
nrow(z) = row.Cells(z).Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "")
z += 1
End If
Next
dt.Rows.Add(nrow)
Next
```

Wouldn't that be close to what you want?

The For-Each iterator loop goes over EVERY element, and you could filter out the unwanted elements as shown.

Or, you could create an array of all indices you want to process, and iterate over that array to process only the columns with only the wanted indices.